# How to detect animated .jpg image after uploading with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, jpeg, image-uploading, gif

I am building a small app with nodejs/expressjs. I made an upload wizard for GIF and JPG images... Depend on images' extension I will classify them into Animated Images or Normal Images...

```
GIF --> Animated Images
JPG --> Normal Images
```

But I got a problem, images in JPG can be animated. So how can I detect animated JPG images?
Demo animated JPG: http://picforest.net/pic/0237bbca82954e74902a4afba66df221

Comment: JPG does not animate. Period.
It's either a series of JPG images rendered with javascript or a GIF file named as a JPG. A web server and browser might still recognize the correct GIF filetype, even if the wrong extension has been added to the filename. You can eventually look at the mime type of the file.

Comment: If you take a look at the magic number of your example, you can see it's *GIF89a*, thus it's a GIF not a JPG

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find out that information using EXIF information.

For instance, here's the EXIF info of the image that you have provided:
http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.picforest.net%2Fupload%2F2015%2F17%2F0237bbca82954e74902a4afba66df221.jpg

It says that it's a GIF image.

There's a node module for exif called https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif. Perhaps that may help you out

Comment: I've try node-exif but it showed nothing from .jpg file and cannot read .gif file.

Comment: GIFs don't have EXIF data.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed in comments, there is no such thing as animated JPEGs (except [this obscure proposal](https://github.com/clipland/animated-jpeg)). Unfortunately this not mean that you can rely on image extension. Extension is just part of file name, it *suggest* file type, but not determines it. For example image you shared has `.jpg` extension, but in reality it's GIF and every major browser will treat it as one. In order to detect animated image you must inspect it's content. For example in case of GIF images you could check if first 6 bytes of file is `GIF89a` or `GIF87a`, but doing so you will know only that image is a GIF, not that image is an *animated* GIF. If you want to detect only animated GIFs you must check if they have multiple Image Descriptor Blocks, and it's a little bit more complicated.

It's also worth to mention that currently there are 3 supported by browsers image formats which could contain animation:

- **GIF** - it's rather obvious;
- **[APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG)** - it's supported by Firefox and Safari, other browsers displays these images as ordinary PNGs;
- **[SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG_animation)** - SMIL animations are supported by all major browsers except IE and Edge, and there are also CSS and ECMAScript animations.

If you want to detect first two types of animation you can use my node.js library - [is-animated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-animated), it's rather simple to use:

```
const isAnimated = require('is-animated');    
isAnimated(someBuffer); // -> true/false
```

Unfortunately currently it doesn't support detecting animated SVGs.